# Search and retrieve xml in dataset?

Tags: c#, xml, dataset

I am trying to find some working examples to learn the wonders on Dataset with XML. Im using this [example](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/cd_catalog.xml) of the xml data. I want to search through all the CD nodes for the TITLE value.

`DataSet dsXml = new DataSet();

dsXml.ReadXml(msXml);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look at using linq2xml.  you could also use linq to "query" the dataset.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/bb688086.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very simple C# code which will print all the "TITLE" in the provided XML:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Xml;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
class Program
 {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DataSet dsXml = new DataSet();
        dsXml.ReadXml("http://www.w3schools.com/xml/cd_catalog.xml");

        for (int i = 0; i < dsXml.Tables.Count; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Table Name: " + dsXml.Tables[i].TableName);
            int j = 1;
            foreach (DataRow myRow in dsXml.Tables[i].Rows)
            {
                Console.Write("[" + j++ + "]");
                foreach (DataColumn myColumn in dsXml.Tables[i].Columns)
                {
                    if (myColumn.ColumnName.Equals("TITLE"))
                        Console.Write("[" + myRow[myColumn] + "]");
                }
                Console.WriteLine("");
            }
        }
    }
 }
}
```